# Unresolved variables/functions in Angular template using WebStorm

Tags: angular, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I use WebStorm to develop in Angular.

Recently I switched from the single project model to the multi project model proposed by Angular, so I ended up with a structure such as the following:

```
my-solution
    dist
    node_modules
    projects
        my-project
        my-library
    [multiple config files]
```

In my `tsconfig.json` file I have the following aliases:

```json
        "paths": {
            "my-library": ["dist/my-library/my-library", "dist/my-library"],
            "@my-project/*": ["projects/my-project/src/*"]
        }
```

Now, I have a component (in my-project) that inherits from an abstract class in my-project that itself inherits from an abstract class in my-library. Let's say:

```js
export abstract class BaseAbstractStep implements OnInit {
 public propertyA;
}
```

```js
import { BaseAbstractStep } from 'my-library';

export abstract class AbstractStep extends BaseAbstractStep{
 public propertyB;
}
```

```js
import { AbstractStep } from '@my-project/path/to/component';

export class Step extends AbstractStep {
 public propertyC;
}
```

When I am in the Angular template of Step with WebStorm, `propertyB` and `propertyC` will be correctly resolved but WebStorm displays an error for `propertyA` that it fails to resolve.

I have noticed that if I change the import in `AbstractStep` to

```js
import { BaseAbstractStep } from "../../../../../../my-library/src/lib/modules/path/to/component";
```

Then WebStorm will be able to resolve all variables and functions in the template (but then it will fail to compile and will create other problems).

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: what IDE build do you use? Similar issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40709) was resolved in 2020.1. If upgrading to the most recent version doesn't help, please file a ticket to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: @lena I'm using WebStorm 2021.2.3 Build #WS-212.5457.55 ; JetBrains Toolbox doesn't suggest any new version so I'm gonna create a ticket as you suggest

Comment: I have the same issue. Was there ever a resolution? Happens in both JetBrains Rider 2022.1.2 and WebStorm 2022.1.3. The component Typescript file works fine, but the HTML template file cannot resolve the base class variables in another project. The funny thing is that it does work for some of my coworkers in WebStorm.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, where IntelliJ displayed "unresolved function or method" and "unresolved variable or type" in some HTML templates.

I found out it was a broken reference in the component class definition. The leading dot was missing. It was defined as

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: '/login.component.html'
})
```

instead of

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
```

Somehow it works correctly during `ng serve` run, but it is displayed as an error by IntelliJ.

(Windows 10, Angular 14, Node 16, npm 8)